# Why class instances in Laravel session automatically update?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I tried to add a class instance to Laravel session

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Object {
    public $age = 10;
}

.....

//Create new object and then put it in session.
$object = new \App\Object();
session()->put('test',$object);


$objectFromSession = session('object');
//Update object. It will update the the instance in session automatically.
$objectFromSession->age += 1;


$data = session('object');
//$data is updated. Why???
dump($data);
```

I wonder to know why this happened?

- Why you`$objectFromSession = session('object');` is a reference not
  a value?
- Why update the instance's variable `$objectFromSession->age += 1;` will automatically save?

Comment: objects are passed by reference, they aren't cloned ... its the same object

Comment: But why they are automatically saved in session without call ?

Comment: you put it in the session ... the session is just holding a reference to the same object you are manipulating, objects are passed by reference

Comment: Also, I tried replace the class instance to an array. 
`       $data = [
        "age"=>10
    ];
    session()->put('object',$data);

    $object = session('object');
    $object['age'] = 20;

    $check = session('object');
    dump($check);
`
It doesn't work. The $object get from session is passed by reference.

Comment: arrays aren't objects ........

Answer (score 2):

Laravel session (which is Symfony session) is a pretty simple container for a data. So, when you store the data in the session, it's just doing this:

```
public function set($name, $value)
{
    $this->attributes[$name] = $value;
}
```

So, [the object is passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

Comment: laravel uses its own session interface, it moved away from symfony's

Comment: @lagbox namespace Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\

Comment: we have our own SessionManager, our own Session Store and our own Session Handlers

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The following solved the issue for me in Laravel 7.

```
  $cartData1 = $request->session()->get('cartData');

  **$cartData  = json_decode(json_encode($cartData1) );**


  if(count($cartData)){
    for ($i=0 ; $i < count($cartData) ; $i++ ) {
       $cartData[$i]->productslug = $this->getProductSlug($cartData[$i]->parent_products_id);
       $cartData[$i]->productDetails= $this->getJson($this->languageregion, $cartData[$i]->productslug  , "product");
    }
  }
```